# Iterating over an array of objects with multiple properties using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects called "Contractors" in which each contractor will be displayed in a box on the screen so they have the properties "id", "posx" and "posy". I want to be able to change the coordinates onclick from what they are currently to a line on the bottom of the screen where they will be displayed sequentially. The code for changing the coordinates works properly but animating the boxes to those coordinates does not.

```
function moveto(){
                $.each(Contractors, function(index, value){                 
                    $(index).animate({top: this.posy},"slow");
                    $(index).animate({left: this.posx},"slow");
                });
            }
```

I'm not sure where the problem is but I'm getting a problem with "Cannot read property 'Default View' of undefined". Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, show us [a demo of your code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You're passing a number to `$()`? Why? What relationship is there between each object in the array, and the elements you want to animate?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity - that's a good point. Perhaps what was intended was $("#"+index).animate(...).

Comment: I would test to make sure your `this.posy` and `this.posx` properties are coming through.

Comment: Ahhhhh thanks so much cliffs! You were completely right, I forgot to select the divs themselves :D if you want to see it, check it out here 

http://jsfiddle.net/lmalcom/4cWWD/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @coderkid DOM ID's can not start with a number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

`index` is a number, so it makes no sense to put it in a jQuery object or call functions on it.

Actually, there are no DOM elements in your function at all, so without seeing more of your code it is impossible to fix.